# can you use metal pans in combo convection/microwave ovens

Tags: equipment

can you use metal pans in combo convection/microwave ovens

Comment: Obviously not when you're using them with microwave..

Answer (score 1):

Can... possibly, if they don't spark too much.

Be used successfully... no.
They will block the microwaves, making the exercise rather futile.

If you're using only conventional heat, then fine, but not if you need the microwave energy.